# New planet Krypton-I

Tags: dc, superman

Can Superman and Supergirl populate an entire new generation of Kryptonians and eventually a planet like Krypton-I, or something? Why not?
So the questions are:

(a) Can they biologically produce more superkids.

(b) If (a) is true, will they be on earth or they will colonize other planet? (like moon then rename it to Krypton-I or something) whether they are able to foster an entire generation.

Comment: I’m a little unsure about what you’re asking here. Are you asking whether it is *biologically* possible for Superman and Supergirl to procreate? Whether such a population would be stable? Whether they could find a new planet similar to Krypton? Whether this will ever happen?

Comment: Yes, biologically possible, not find a planet, but move to other and stay there then eventually it will be called something like Krypton.

Comment: So…which of those things are you asking about?

Comment: Is this possible biologically? If yes then second question is whether to move to other planet or not.

Comment: So you are asking whether the entire rather specific sequence of events could happen?

Comment: I am asking if the event could happen as whole, obviously if they cant populate (biologically) then the question about planet is rather useless, is it?

Comment: I’d say that’s two questions, then: (a) Could Superman and Supergirl biologically be the progenitors of the new Kryptonian species? and (b) Could  they find another planet similar to Krypton? We try to avoid multiple questions in one. Perhaps you could edit this question to focus on the first one, and then ask the second part separately.

Comment: No no, find another planet, No. Let me edit the question it is confusing I guess.

Comment: It still looks like two questions to me, although you’ve made it more clear. The first one has a definite answer, whereas the second is probably opinion-based (*if* Superman and Supergirl had children, where would they live? wherever the writer wanted them too). I’m voting to close as “too broad” because these are two distinct questions.

Comment: Shoot! I was in the middle of posting an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need more than 2 people to form the basis of a genetically stable population - especially those that are not already related by blood (Superman and Supergirl are cousins, after all).

Comment: If the Super-family don’t mind some human genetic material being mixed in, I’ve decided I’m willing to lend my assistance to this noble endeavour.